# $elemMatch on nested Embedded Document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

In my Mongoose, I have the follow schema ..

```
const RobotSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
});

const RobotClassRoomSchema = new Schema({
  robot: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Robot' },
});

const ClassRoomSchema = new Schema({
  robots: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'RobotClassRoom' }],
});
```

How can I verify if there are any `Robot` with Id: `59226c258a4a131c6828841e` in my `ClassRoom`?

## Attempt

[image]

**But I there are robots..**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema is using references to objects in another collection. Since MongoDB itself is really only querying on one collection at a time, the "referenced" data does not exist in the collection you are querying on.

All that collection knows about is that it has an "array" field that contains `ObjectId` values, that actually mean nothing to MongoDB itself and the only thing that knows where that `ObjectId` value actually refers to is defined in your mongoose schema in "client code". So the server of course knows nothing of this.

### Using MongoDB

In modern releases of MongoDB ( at least 3.2 ) you can use the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation pipeline operator to perform a "join" ( or rather a "lookup" ) on the server. This syntax allows you to define the collection you want to "look in" for the value found in the array and the result will retrieve the matched object from the referenced collection into your document.

The catch with arrays is that depending on your version it may require treatment with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in order to do the match. MongoDB 3.2 requires the array be "un-wound", but in MongoDB 3.4 you are supposed to be able to do this:

```
db.getCollection('classrooms').aggregate([
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "robotclassrooms",
        "localField": "robots",
        "foreignField": "_id"
        "as": "robots"
    }},
    { "$redact": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": {
           "$anyElementTrue": {
             "$map": {
               "input": "$robots",
               "as": "r",
               "in": { "$eq": [ "$$r.robot", ObjectId("59226c258a4a131c6828841e") ] }
             }
           }
        },
        "then": "$$KEEP",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
      }
    }}
])
```

And using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/):

```
db.getCollection('classrooms').aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$robots" },
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "robotclassrooms",
        "localField": "robots",
        "foreignField": "_id"
        "as": "robots"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$robots" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "_id",
      "updatedAt": { "$first": "$updatedAt" },
      "createdAt": { "$first": "$createdAt" },
      "code": { "$first": "$code" },
      "createdBy": { "$first": "$createdBy" },
      "robots": { "$push": "$robots" }
    }},
    { "$redact": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": {
           "$anyElementTrue": {
             "$map": {
               "input": "$robots",
               "as": "r",
               "in": { "$eq": [ "$$r.robot", ObjectId("59226c258a4a131c6828841e") ] }
             }
           }
        },
        "then": "$$KEEP",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
      }
    }}
])
```

Note the double usage of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in that case, since not only does MongoDB 3.2 require the array to be unwound before processing, but the result is also an "array", even though it may only match a single value. The [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator does not distinguish between singular and multiple matches as **always** returns an array. In any version.

Hence also the follow up treatment with [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to restore the document structure. I'm not reproducing **all** of your document properties here, but just enough of them so you get the general "gist".

---

### Using Mongoose

The alternate process to actually asking the "server" to do this action is to white the code using "mongoose" to do a "populate query". This is a "client side emulation" of a "join", where what actually happens under the covers are multiple requests made to the database with the results being "merged" in code.

Naturally, as a "client side" operation there are some limitations to this. Most notably the server will return **all** results, whether they meet your criteria or not and the condition is evaluated in "client code".

```
Classroom.find()
  .populate({
    path: 'robots',
    match: { 'robot': '59226c258a4a131c6828841e' }
  }).exec(function(err,docs) {
     // docs has all classrooms but some robots arrays will be empty

  });
```

So the catch here is that evert "classrooms" document is always returned, even though the condition was to only "populate" those objects from "robotsclassrooms" that matched the given query condition.

The result is "classroom" objects that have an "empty array" where the query was not met. You would then need to counter that, but "filtering" the resulting classroom documents for empty arrays, like so:

```
Classroom.find()
  .populate({
    path: 'robots',
    match: { 'robot': '59226c258a4a131c6828841e' }
  }).exec(function(err,docs) {
      docs = docs.filter(function(doc) { return doc.robots.length > 0 })
      // Now docs is only matching documents containing the requested ObjectId value
  });
```

---

### Conclusion

Those are basically your options, and which one you use depends on your approach and of course the available server features.

Note that these procedures are "finding documents that match the element in the array", which is a different statement to "returning only the matching element of the array". There are different techniques to that which "build on" the processes here, but basically involve "filtering" the array content as well. For instance, in the aggregation framework you can apply [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) as an operator to do that function.

**Notes:**

See also the full list of [Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) for other operators used in the examples.

Comment: Could you please help with my related question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206844/find-one-document-from-whole-collection-with-one-specific-value-nested-inside-m